# Doubt about definition of coordinate ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was trying to solve this question:

> Prove that $\mathbb{A}^1$ is not isomorphic to any of its proper open subset.

One of the solutions I looked up said that the coordinate rings are not isomorphic.

I know that for a closed set $Y$ the coordinate ring is defined as $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I(Y)$. But how is the coordinate ring of an open set defined?

Comment: An example: The coordinate ring of $\Bbb A^1\setminus \{a\}$ is $k\left[x, \frac1{x-a}\right]$. It's isomorphic to the planar curve given by the graph of $y=\frac1{x-a}$ via projection onto the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Any open set $U$ is a complement to a closed set $X\setminus U$. The coordinate ring of $U$ is then the [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_of_a_ring) $R_{I(X\setminus U)}$ of the full ring $R$ by the ideal $I(X\setminus U)$. The idea is to make all elements of $I(X\setminus U)$ invertible, thus effectively *removing* the areas where they are zero (as functions), which is by definition $X\setminus U$.